# Acces item in a content type CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm doing a small application which read data from my sharepoint list, my code works when my colum is not in a content type:

```
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("myList");
    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
    l_objCtx.Load(items, its => its.Include(item => item[ColumnName], item => item.Id));
    l_objCtx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
          m_strGetprimary = item.Id.ToString();
          return true;
    }
```

But if I used my code with a column which in a content type, I get the following error:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Any idea of how can I read these items?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I add Contacts Content Type in a list and test the code snippet below:
[image]

[image]

Make sure the fields you needed to access have been add in its.Include lamda expression and the field name should be internal field name.

Comment: Thank you
I retried it but it's not working
On which Sharepoint do you try it?
I'M using Sharepoint 2016

Comment: Thank, I think I found the root cause of my trouble
you have to add all fields you need, before to declare the content type
Becauese if I declare a content type, I add the field I need in my content type (which already exists), it won't work
So you have to define all fields you need and then declare your content type
Once again, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi Arozora, you are welcome and yes, it ned to defind the fields needed. If my reply is helpful to you, you could accept as answer so that it could help others who stuck in the same issue in the forum.